# Jquery- Checkbox selection should lead to popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements which are displated in the tabular form as show below . These are being fetched from a rails backend.

[image]

Now i want to be able to set up remainders based on the selection of each check list. If i select one of the elements in a checklist i should get a popup which reads 'Store name','Category' and generates a form. Once this form has been successfully submitted i want to enable the corresponding checkbox as enabled. I need a Jquery expert to help me on how to achieve this . I can put a popup based on selection of a checkbox , but how do i bind it to the specific record? The form submission will happen via JSON and i will take care of that .

Comment: you can send the Id of the corresponding row to fetch the specific record on the popup. Use jquery ajax for that and after submitting ur form in ajax in success function add class to specific checkbox to get selectd

Comment: Thanks , can u give me a short example code . I am a Jquery newbie hence finding it challenging.

Comment: Is the table rendered as an HTML table?

Comment: Yes the table is rendered as a HTML table ...

Comment: And there is a unique id for each row?

Comment: @ankur http://moneyoga.com/test/Response_summary.html.. is is the file which am working with .

Comment: @slacker no i dont have a unique id for each row . Have sent u the HTML code http://moneyoga.com/test/Response_summary.html

Comment: If each row has id then use `$(this).parent()` to get the row and fetch the values accordingly

Comment: @Avinash: then how are you planning to bind the dialogue to a specific row?

Comment: @Avinash: And I cudnt see any tables in the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$( "#table_id" ).find( 'input[type=checkbox]' ).live( 'change', function ()
        {
            if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) )
            {

                var _row = $( this ).parent().parent();//to get the selected row
                var row_id= $( _row ).find( 'td:eq(1)' ).text();//assuming the id field is the 2nd column
...................................
                //code to pop up dialog
.............................
               }

        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally achieve by defining my own attributes.
So in the check box, while painting the screen, I would add an attribute - say "store-id" and enter the corresponding store id value.
If you are building the DOM using jQuery on the browser then u can do this

```
$(<selector>).attr("store-id",jsonObject.store_id);
```

Now, i will bind a change event to all the select objects, by either binding it over a class or any other appropriate jQuery selector.

```
$(<selector for checkbox>).change(function(){ var attr = $(this).attr("store-id"); // Do some operation });
```

And then use your JSON to retrive more data and show it